# BeautifulSoup find text contents

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an html doc that I want to find/replace given text.

```
<body>I am looking for this text within the document</body>
```

I can do:

```
soup.find(lambda x: 'this text' in x.text)
```

But that gives me a Tag object.  Is there any way to get a NavigableString and/or the actual position of 'this text'?

I'd sure hate to have to search, and then search for the same thing again.

Comment: I don't see why its an issue to search twice  -- python doesn't make it that hard: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_index.htm

Answer (score 0):

text is just a property of the object returned by soup.find()

```
soup.find(lambda x: 'this text' in x.text).text
```

you're accessing it in your lambda function, but not on your object once soup.find() returns it